# Weird deprecation warning in tsort.rb about static_assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deprecation-warning

When I deploy with `capistrano` in `production` I get the error below. But in `staging` I do not get the warning message.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in tsort_each at /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226)
```

Also, both my production.rb and staging.rb environment files have the following line commented: 
    # config.serve_static_files = true

Comment: Please show full backtrace and relevant parts of your Gemfile.

Comment: It's just a depreciation warning, well, search `serve_static_assets` in project folder I am sure you would find `serve_static_assets` replace it with `serve_static_files` and deploy happily. well, It's just for peace of your mind :) !!!

Comment: The problem is that i cannot find serve_static_assets referenced anywhere! the production.rb and staging.rb config files are very similar and both without that settings...

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i realized that long time ago i added a gem to make the app work on Heroku.

After moving away from heroku, that gem remained in the Gemfile and was causing the error.
I fixed it by **removing** the following:

```
gem 'rails_12factor'
```